# Stripe payment sent to SQS not send right now... with lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

## What I imagine

On my website, I have a form to buy a product. Information needed are email and domain name.
Payment are managed by stripe and I use Lambda and API gateway to verify payment information.
If payment is successful, I'm sending email and domain name to SQS.

## What I've got

The data is not sent to SQS right after the validation.
I don't know why but the first use of the form, nothing is set to SQS ; 
the second time the form is used, data form the first form are send to SQS ; the third time the form is used, it's data of the second form they are send to SQS, etc...

## Cant' find the problem on the lambda code

```
const stripe = require('stripe')("sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
const ApiBuilder = require('claudia-api-builder');
const querystring = require('querystring');
var api = new ApiBuilder();
var aws  = require('aws-sdk');
var sqs = new aws.SQS();

api.post('/stripe',request => {
    let params = querystring.parse(request.body);

    return stripe.charges.create({
        amount: params.package,
        currency: 'eur',
        description: `foo 12 month charge`,
        source: params.stripeToken,
        receipt_email: params.email,
        metadata: {domain_name: params.domain_name, email: params.email},
    }).then(charge => {
        console.log("Data to send in SQS :" + {domain_name:     params.domain_name, email: params.email});
        var sqsMsg = {domain_name: params.domain_name, email: params.email};
        console.log("Data in variable : sqsMsg");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(sqsMsg));
        sendToSQS(JSON.stringify(sqsMsg));

        return charge;
    }).catch((err) => {
        return err;
    }, { success: { contentType: 'text/html'}});
});

function sendToSQS(data) {
    var params = {
        MessageBody: JSON.stringify(data),
        QueueUrl: 'https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/98XXXXXXXXXXX/foo-new-order',
        DelaySeconds: 0
    };
    sqs.sendMessage(params, function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log('Sending Data to SQS Queue Successful ', data);
        }
    });
}

module.exports = api;
```

If someone, can explain me what's wrong. Thanks :)

Comment: When you're calling sendToSQS() you pass in a JSON stringified object. Then inside sendToSQS() you JSON stringify it a second time. Why? Also, I hope you have a plan for how to deal with Lambda retries so that you don't accidentally make multiple Stripe charges for a single transaction (or that Stripe can detect and ignore duplicates).

Comment: Root cause here is that you are not being consistently asynchronous.  You can't call your `sendToSQS()` function and immediately return, because that function is non-blocking... but it uses callbacks when it creates the SQS request... it doesn't return a promise and so doesn't interoperate correctly into the rest of the code. Someone with a more thorough grasp of promises than me should be able to clarify this.  The behavior you are seeing is actually expected, as your code is currently written.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I have a better understanding of what"s wrong. I need to find a solution.

Jarmod, indeed I remove one of the JSON.stringify, and yes Stripe manage duplicate :)